# Prioritize\speed up stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure with loops and what not inside and recursive calling of other stored procedure and recursive calling of the stored procedure itself. This stored procedure has a lot of business logic inside it and I won't go into the detail of the actual code, I've already tweaked it as much as possible from a code point of view and also realize that having too much business logic in the actual stored isn't a best practice.

A part from this I was wondering if there is something that can be done to tell SQL to prioritize this single stored procedure or in some way have it use more resources to be faster or make it faster from a system point of view in any way?

I tried this question on stackoverflow but they correctly pointed out that the website is more for code related problems and this is more a server side question so I'm trying it here.

Thank you

Comment: The consensus on StackOverflow was that you needed to fix your code to not use "loops and what not" but your Q was unanswerable as we needed more details about what it is doing. There isn't a magic "go faster" option you can apply to the stored proc. You could mess around with the resource governor but this kind of issue should be fixed at the code level

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you that was the answer I was looking for. There is no go faster option or similar.